# Formtastic select boxes, radio buttons, etc. are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I currently have **active_admin**(which uses formtastic also) installed, and of course **formtastic** itself as well.

Please take a look at the following code:

```
<%= f.inputs :hero_id, :as => :select, :collection => Hero.find(:all) %> 
<%= f.inputs :name %> 
<%= f.inputs :starting_items, :as => :select, :collection => Item.find(:all) %> 
<%= f.inputs :early_items, :as => :select, :collection => Item.find(:all) %> 
<%= f.inputs :core_items, :as => :select, :collection => Item.find(:all) %> 
<%= f.inputs :situational_items, :as => :select, :collection => Item.find(:all) %>  

<%= f.buttons %>
```

This exact same code displays the select boxes populated with data just fine in **active_admin**. 
However, on my website itself it will only display text_fields, no select boxes whatsoever!

Anyone know what might be the problem here?
Because I have several other forms on my website I can fix if I can get this to work properly. All of the forms are just displays text_fields instead of select boxes, radio buttons, check boxes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `f.input` instead of `f.inputs`.